# how to fix TypeError: window.getComputedStyle(...) is null in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using zepto for drag and swap it works perfectly in chrome but showing error in firefox. Below is the section of the script of  dragswap in which it is showing error. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
 `; (function ($) {
        $.fn.dragswap = function (options) {
            var dragSrcEl;
            function getPrefix() {
                var el = document.createElement('p'),
                getPre, transforms = {
                    'webkitAnimation': '-webkit-animation',
                    'OAnimation': '-o-animation',
                    'msAnimation': '-ms-animation',
                    'MozAnimation': '-moz-animation',
                    'animation': 'animation'
                };
                document.body.insertBefore(el, null);
                for (var t in transforms) {
                    if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                        el.style[t] = "translate3d(1px,1px,1px)";
                        // if(window.getComputedStyle && (style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null)) !== null) 
                             getPre = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(transforms[t]);
                        // return the successful prefix
                        return t;
                    }
                }

                document.body.removeChild(el);

            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox has a bug in which if the element is `"display: none"` then `window.getComputedStyles` will return `null`.

The below is where I found this knowledge which fixed the error in my third-party code. Note In my case the element was also an iFrame
https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries/issues/148